# JMeter throws o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null error

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter throws  ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Script using loop controller code ${__groovy(vars.get("continueLoop") == "true")}

Note : csv data file has 2 rows of data .I am executing test for 1 user only.

2018-12-07 10:51:20,773 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsBoolean(AbstractTestElement.java:249) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.getClearEachIteration(CookieManager.java:146) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.testIterationStart(CookieManager.java:431) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyTestListeners(JMeterThread.java:971) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$IterationListener.iterationStart(JMeterThread.java:1054) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where you initialize continueLoop to true and where you change it to false.

You should show jmeter.log content (use pastebin or simular applications) as it certainly contains important information to help you.

See a working example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1-SNAPSHOT.20181206">
      <hashTree>
        <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="continueLoop" elementType="Argument">
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">continueLoop</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">true</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
        </TestPlan>
        <hashTree>
          <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
              <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
          </ThreadGroup>
          <hashTree>
            <WhileController guiclass="WhileControllerGui" testclass="WhileController" testname="WC" enabled="true">
              <stringProp name="WhileController.condition">${__groovy(vars.get(&quot;continueLoop&quot;) == &quot;true&quot;)}</stringProp>
            </WhileController>
            <hashTree>
              <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
                <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
              </DebugSampler>
              <hashTree/>
              <TestAction guiclass="TestActionGui" testclass="TestAction" testname="Think Time" enabled="true">
                <intProp name="ActionProcessor.action">1</intProp>
                <intProp name="ActionProcessor.target">0</intProp>
                <stringProp name="ActionProcessor.duration">0</stringProp>
              </TestAction>
              <hashTree>
                <UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Pause" enabled="true">
                  <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">100</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">100</stringProp>
                </UniformRandomTimer>
                <hashTree/>
              </hashTree>
              <IfController guiclass="IfControllerPanel" testclass="IfController" testname="If Controller" enabled="true">
                <stringProp name="IfController.condition">${__jexl3(${__jm__WC__idx} == 10,)}</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="IfController.evaluateAll">false</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="IfController.useExpression">true</boolProp>
              </IfController>
              <hashTree>
                <TestAction guiclass="TestActionGui" testclass="TestAction" testname="Flow Control Action" enabled="true">
                  <intProp name="ActionProcessor.action">1</intProp>
                  <intProp name="ActionProcessor.target">0</intProp>
                  <stringProp name="ActionProcessor.duration">0</stringProp>
                </TestAction>
                <hashTree>
                  <UserParameters guiclass="UserParametersGui" testclass="UserParameters" testname="User Parameters" enabled="true">
                    <collectionProp name="UserParameters.names">
                      <stringProp name="-753878037">continueLoop</stringProp>
                    </collectionProp>
                    <collectionProp name="UserParameters.thread_values">
                      <collectionProp name="-544885953">
                        <stringProp name="97196323">false</stringProp>
                      </collectionProp>
                    </collectionProp>
                    <boolProp name="UserParameters.per_iteration">false</boolProp>
                  </UserParameters>
                  <hashTree/>
                </hashTree>
              </hashTree>
            </hashTree>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </jmeterTestPlan>
```